# casting from a var type to a different class

Tags: c#, .net, azure

casting a var  type objects to  array of a class.

in my example I can query from the table all elements. but the problem is when i cast it, it just doesnt cast all instances. 
any help??

Answer (score 1):

There's no such type as "a var type". A declaration using `var` just makes the compiler *infer* the type of the variable. It's still statically typed, and works as if you'd explicitly declared it - although it allows you to declare variables which use an *anonymous type*.

In your case we don't know what any of the methods involved do, which means we can't really tell what's going on. It sounds like `Query` is probably of type `IEnumerable<AccessPointItem>`. You'll need to express in code how to convert from an `AccessPointItem` to an `AccessPoint`.

A few points to note:

- Your query expression is somewhat pointless - you probably *just* want to call `tsvc.CreateQuery<AccessPointItem>()`
- Conventionally, local variables in C# use camel casing (starting with lower case letters) not Pascal case
- You create an array for no purpose - why?
- `Select()` will never return null, so you don't need to check for it
- Calling `Cast` will attempt to just cast each `AccessPointItem` to `AccessPoint`... is that really what you intended?

Comment: what I exactly need is to convert AccessPointItem to AccessPoint( array of AccessPoint objects in this case)

Comment: @JOY: Well we don't know anything about the `AccessPoint` and `AccessPointItem` classes... are they standard classes somewhere, or are they your own?

Comment: They are my own classes. the two classes are has almost the same properties. and I need to use the AccessPoint class in my controller. so that after I get the values(as AccessPointItem) from the table. I need to cast them to a different class objects(AccessPoint)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're you're mixing up your classes `AccessPoint` and `AccessPointItem`. Try this:

```
public static AccessPoint[] getAllAps()
{
    return tsvc.CreateQuery<AccessPoint>("AccessPointTable").ToArray();
}
```

or this:

```
public static AccessPointItem[] getAllAps()
{ 
    return tsvc.CreateQuery<AccessPointItem>("AccessPointTable").ToArray();
}
```

Comment: In the table there are of type AccessPointItem items. and need to cast them and return as AccessPoint objects.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `AccessPoint` and `AccessPointItem`.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the types involved.

First you read `AccessPointItem`:

```
var Query = from APs in tsvc.CreateQuery<AccessPointItem>(...)
```

Then you try to cast it to `AccessPoint`:

```
return Query.Cast<AccessPoint>()
```

You're gonna need to implement some kind of conversion method in order for that to work (unfortunately I never did it myself, but from a quick Google run I see plenty of info about the subject is available). I'll give it a shot off the top of my head:

```
//inside AccessPointItem.cs
public static AccessPoint ToAccessPoint(this AccessPointItem item) // extension method looks good for the job
{
    AccessPoint retObj = new AccessPoint();
    // assign properties from 'item' to 'retObj'
    return retObj;
}

//Usage example in your case
return Query.Select(singleAccessPointItem => singleAccessPointItem.ToAccessPoint());
```

Comment: yes That is what I exactly need to do. and google seems not offering any help :(

Comment: @JOY I tried to put together some code, it's just a proof of concept but might help